# различие в чем-либо и различие чего-либо

Tags: предлоги, управление

"Различие в видах выращиваемых растений"/"различие видов выращиваемых растений" определяет конкурентоспособность некоторых предприятий сельского хозяйства.
Как сказать правильно и каковы нюансы, если оба варианта правильны?

Comment: Надо "между"! – –

Comment: @oleedd различие между видах, различие между видами?

Comment: @Буратино Второе, конечно.

Answer (score 1):

Лучше так: ***Различие в видах** выращиваемых растений **определяет** конкурентоспособность некоторых предприятий сельского хозяйства.*

Сравнить: ***Различие видов** растений связано со следующими признаками..*. (О классификации растений.)

Различать виды (В.п) –  различение видов (Р.п.).

Но: различие в видах (П.п.).

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**

Думаю, что различие ***в видах*** (не в виде) – это корректно.

***Вид** — основная единица систематики... Близкие виды образуют роды, **роды** объединяются в семейства, родственные семейства растений объединяются в порядки, порядки — в классы, классы — в отделы, а отделы составляют царство Растения.*

Поэтому на одном предприятии может быть **несколько видов растений**.

Comment: Тут различие относится к выращиваемых, *различие выращиваемых* растений определяется конкурентоспособностью предприятий. Или виды выращиваемых растений определяются конкурентоспособностью. Различие в видах - это плеоназм.

Comment: НУ или вообще надо передать фразу в: конкурентоспособность предприятий с/х определяет какие виды растений будут выращиваться. Я очень сомневаюсь вообще, что можно писать различие в видах.

Comment: При перестановке виден нужный смысл.: Различие в видах растений, выращиваемых в хозяйствах,  определяет их  конкурентоспособность. Но зачем нам обособленный оборот. Поэтому надо сравнивать варианты: различие в видах и различие видов. Первый лучше. Плеоназма не вижу, а вот различие видов больше подходит к теме классификации растений.

Comment: Виды - это уже классификация, то есть уже различие, различия в видах не может быть, потому что это различие в различии. Различие в родах, различие в классах, различия в семействах - так не говорят совсем. Даже яша не ищет таких словосочетаний. Единственное иногда говорят различие в классе - в единственном числе, значит, что класс отличается и отличие принципиальное.

Comment: Просто сравните с другими фразами: *различия в ответах; различия в книгах, различия в растениях*. Нормально?

Answer (score 0):

В указание на конкретизацию отличия.

Различие в видах растений. - различие растений, но в видах. Что - различие, различие чего - растений. Различие растений в чём? - в видах. На самом деле кривоватая фраза, так как вид - это просто названия различия(и сходства) форм чего-то, так что тут плеоназм, вроде как маслянистость в масле продуктов.

Различие видов растений. - растений дополнение, относящее к слову видов. Различие чего - видов, видов чего - растений. Здесь нет плеоназма, потому что различие не относится к слову растений. Маслянистость масел продуктов.

Касательное того, как же написать с предлогом **В**? Тогда определяемое слово употребляют в единственном числе:

Различие автомобилей в классе. Различие в классе автомобилей.

Хотя, это скорее всего сокращение или упрощение через сокращение от фраз вроде:

Различие скоростного режима у автомобилей в классе / различие скоростного режима в классе автомобилей / скоростной режим в классе автомобилей - автомобилей в классе, это цельная фраза от автомобильный класс или классный автомобиль. И в этом предложении, скорее всего Различие - подлежащее, а в классе автомобилей - это сказуемое. Различие - это различные **характеристики**, которые являются основными для категории **класса**, то как выделяется класс автомобилей, а не классы. Классы - это уже деление содержащее условие.

То есть, **если различие и союз В, то такие слова как: вид, класс, род и прочие таксономические термины следует писать в единственном числе.**

То есть есть различия индивидуальные: цвет автомобиля, а есть различия классовые - скажем тип кузова и прочее, поэтому *в классе* - это уточнение о каком типе различий идет речь, не о индивидуальных, а о категориальных различиях.

**Различие/ия в виде** выращиваемых растений.

**Различие в цвете** растений, а не *различие в цветах* растений.

В общем, как мог)

Answer (score 0):

**Комментарий к ответу**

Запишите, пожалуйста, фразу полностью  в том варианте, который вы считаете **правильным**.  Я думаю, что это первое, что нужно обозначить в ответе на заданный вопрос, иначе окружающим вас **трудно понять**.  Запись заданного предложения должна быть **оптимальной,** то есть кратко и четко передавать нужное содержание и не быть кривоватой на слух.

Вы выбираете второй вариант (различие видов), **он идеален?**  Или есть еще третий и четвертый?  Наша речь по большому счету вообще можно считать «кривоватой». Мы не можем передать все **нюансы смысла**,  о которых вы говорите,  все тонкости мыслей, так как у нас **ограниченный** набор речевых вариантов — всего-то шесть основных падежей.  А обмениваться мыслями без речевой формулировки мы пока еще не можем, это дело будущего.

Вот и приходится **выбирать**, что лучше (или что хуже).  Содержание сообщения видится ясно в обоих случаях,  но второй вариант  больше подходит к теме классификации растений и поэтому здесь **кажется кривоватым**. Это **мое** мнение.

Нам бы не пришлось вообще обсуждать наши ответы, если бы вы точно определились со **своим** мнением и записали его в понятной для всех форме. Тогда бы это было два разных варианта, предложенных автору и участникам форума. **Неясное изложение**  своей точки зрения — это ведь тоже существенный речевой недостаток ответа, не правда ли?